# Find the lowest leaf in a binary tree

Tags: c++, c, binary-tree

i'm trying to compare all leafs to return the lowest value of a tree, I don't have main function just a script to insert values so unfortunately I can't debug it.

```
tpNoArvore * findLowest(tpNoArvore * pNo){
   tpNoArvore * left;
   tpNoArvore * right;
   tpNoArvore * res;

   if (!pNo) return NULL; /* if */

   left = findLowest(pNo->pNoL);
   right = findLowest(pNo->pNoR);
   if(isLeaf(pNo))
      return pNo;
   }  /* if */

   if(!left){
      return right;
   } /* if */

   if(!right){
      return left;
   } /* if */


    return (left->Valor < right->Valor) ? left : right ;

}
```

So, basically what i'm trying to achieve here is to compare the two sides of each node to find the lowest.

Comment: You haven't told us what you want in quite a few boundary cases. For example, what do you want to do in case of a tie (two or more nodes at the same depth)?

Comment: where is `Valor` set? (This is the key to make this work)

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange that your code returns a pointer. I would expect something like:

```
// Assume valor is int
int findLowest(tpNoArvore * pNo){

   if (!pNo) exit(1); /* fatal error */

   // If this is a leaf just return its value
   if(isLeaf(pNo)) return pNo->Valor;

   // Not a leaf

   // Find the lowest value in left part of tree
   int leftValor = findLowest(pNo->pNoL);

   // Find the lowest value in right part of tree
   int rightValor = findLowest(pNo->pNoR);

   // Return the lowest of leftValue ans rightValue
   return (leftValor < rightValor) ? leftValor : rightValor ;

}
```

But maybe I have misundetstood your question.